# Userform_Initialize Null String On Reopen

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I have setup a VBA Userform (in a word document) on Initialize it is set so that a combobox (MoniesInDescription) populates via an external Excel File.

It works all fine, except after I have saved my document and reopen if I try to run the code i get 'Run Time Error 94 : Invalid Use of Null'. I haven't changed any data.

I have had this a couple of times with Userform_Initialize codes, suddenly not working I am unsure why?

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()


Dim statement As String
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\Users\m\Desktop\csvalues.xls;" & _
              "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes'"
conn.Open

statement = "SELECT [Sale Monies In] FROM [Description$]"

Set rs = conn.Execute(statement, , adCmdText)

 With MoniesInDescription
 Do Until rs.EOF
.AddItem CStr(rs.Fields("Sale Monies In").Value)
 rs.MoveNext
 Loop
 End With

 rs.Close
 conn.Close

 End Sub
```

Comment: try `.AddItem CStr(rs.Fields("SaleMonies").Value)`

Comment: I do not understand you. What you mean by "*Setup parameters for Numbers*" and "*add any type of data to the range*"? Provide example.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```js
.AddItem CStr(rs.Fields('" & SaleMonies & "').Value)
```

I hope it supports to your requirement.